# How can I enable camera flash for NativeCameraView in OpenCV

Tags: android, flash, opencv, camera

I have to turn on camera flash using OpenCV. I need to use `NativeCameraView` but

```
mCamera.set(Highgui.CV_CAP_PROP_ANDROID_FOCUS_MODE,
    Highgui.CV_CAP_ANDROID_FLASH_MODE_ON);
```

doesn't work. What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

i guess you mixed two things up here: you are using FOCUS and FLASH within the same set-method.

here is what you did:

```
mCamera.set(Highgui.CV_CAP_PROP_ANDROID_FOCUS_MODE,
Highgui.CV_CAP_ANDROID_FLASH_MODE_ON);
```

here is what you actually should do:

```
mCamera.set(Highgui.CV_CAP_PROP_ANDROID_FLASH_MODE,
Highgui.CV_CAP_ANDROID_FLASH_MODE_ON);
```

you see the difference? btw, if you want continuous light from your flash, you can not use FLASH_MODE_ON, but FLASH_MODE_TORCH:

```
mCamera.set(Highgui.CV_CAP_PROP_ANDROID_FLASH_MODE,
Highgui.CV_CAP_ANDROID_FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
```